# pyspark-Using the maximum value create a loop of row values from 0 to that value for a column and by repeating other column values for it

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below

```
Category   Descrption Max_value ... Total_months
 A         Keyboard   0              5
 B         Monitor    5              7
```

so what I am expecting is below where till the total_months from zero to that value, the rest of the columns repeat itself.

```
 Category  Description Max_value ... months
  A        Keyborad    0               0
  A        Keyborad    0               1
  A        Keyboard    0               2
  A        Keyborad    0               3
  A        Keyborad    0               4
  A        Keyboard    0               5
  B        Monitor     5               0
  B        Monitor     5               1
  B        Monitor     5               2
  B        Monitor     5               3
  B        Monitor     5               4
  B        Monitor     5               5
  B        Monitor     5               6
  B        Monitor     5               7
```

For this in SAS I wrote like this

```
DATA FINAL_table;
SET INITIAL_table;
IF MAX_value NE . THEN DO;
DO months = 0 TO Total_months;

  OUTPUT;
END;
END;
ELSE DO;
months = .;
OUTPUT;
END;
RUN;
```

How to achieve in pyspark this dataframe? I want to chart this later on so need for every month a datapoint.Note this is not calendar months so it could be more than 12.I don't want to use pandas or numpy for this,since conversion later on becomes difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a sequence, and then explode:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sequence = F.udf(lambda x: list(range(x+1)), 'array<int>')

df2 = df.withColumn('months', F.explode(sequence('Total_months')))
```

Comment: Error  is there an alterative to sequence-"Undefined function: 'sequence'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'

Comment: @viji I edited my answer to use a Python UDF for this purpose. It should work now  hopefully :)